# Not able to apply filter on sharepoint list folder via Graph API , also custom columns are not coming via Graph API

Tags: sharepoint

I have sharepoint site where Client List is there. Inside this list there are more folders and inside these folders there are files present. So I am using Graph REST API to access sharepoint list folders file data. I am not able to do two below things.

a) I want to apply filter on list folders i.e items. I used below url to apply filter but its working.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/Client/Items?filter=id eq '1'
```

b) I used below url to access folder files but its result is not showing custom columns which I have created on sharepoint sites.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/Client/items/{itemid}/driveitem/children
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If the column does not have a value,it may not show in return value.

Comment: ?expand=fields is working fine. only filter condition is not working at all. i tried all possible combination . but no luck.

Comment: What is your filter condition?

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/Client/Items?filter=id eq '1'.

Comment: You could  use /Items/1.